# autoincrease cron's execution time by 1 minute every 24hrs

Tags: bash, cron

I'm trying to automate some routine work, which I required and allowed to do only once every 24 hours.

**Requirements:**

I need to open website, login and click check in button once and then I'm allowed to do the same after 24hrs.

**Problem:**

I already have automation for doing the login-clicking job, but the problem that if I run the script same time it could be the issue when I do this actions 1 minute before it's allowed. Example

```
day 1: 00:00:00 start -> 00:00:10 login -> 00:00:15 click Check in
```

Next time I can click check in button after 00:00:15

```
day2: 00:00:00 start -> 00:00:10 login -> 00:00:14 click Checkin
```

Here I get the issue, it click before I'm allowed, so I'm cron will only rerun it on the next 24 hours.

**Solution:**

The idea I have in my head is to in the end of every execution increase cron time by 1 minute

day 1: `33 23 * * * /root/clicker.sh`

day 2: `34 23 * * * /root/clicker.sh`
...

Anybody can suggest example how to increment existing value in cron? Also keep in mind about change the hour after minute 59.

Another solution I though is to add something like `SLEEP 60*DAYS` before executing script and also increase it every day, but not sure how can I get a generate number correctly

Comment: "Everyday only once" and not twice within a 24-hour period are subtly different.  Are you sure it would complain if you did it e.g. day 1 in the evening, then day 2 in the morning (or alternatively every day at midday)?

Comment: I don't think there's anything more elegant or robust than the obvious; figure out how long to sleep, then sleep for that long. I would start with a daily `cron` job and have it figure out when the previous one ran.

Comment: Just start a single script once on each reboot. It enters a loop in which it does its clicking then sleeps 24*3600 seconds and goes around again.

Comment: "Every day" means every 24hrs

Comment: The approach I'm using doesn't allow me to have script constantly running and sleep as it has execution timeout (Playwright framework)

Comment: But only once in a 24 hour period is not the same as every day - 23:59 then 00:01 are 2 minutes apart, but are still only once every day over 2 days.

Comment: thank you Steve. I changed the title and description to be more clear. Now it should be clear that I'm allowed to click once in 24 hrs. Any way both limitations would have a difference only at first iteration, the following days would have same time.
day 1: 23.59; day 2: 00:01; day 3: 00:01 (again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Naive approach: counter inside script**

You can store sleep delta in some file and then increment it, while having cronjob unchanged, i.e.

1. Create file called delta.txt

   ```
   echo 1 > delta.txt
   ```
2. Inside your script, create variable DELTA, which will increment value, stored in delta.txt

   ```
   DELTA="$((10 + $(cat delta.txt)))"
   ```
3. Sleep inside your script for DELTA amount

   ```
   sleep "$DELTA"
   ```
4. Set delta.txt to current DELTA value

   ```
   echo "$DELTA" > delta.txt
   ```
5. Execute rest of your script

This is a pretty naive implementation, which will obviously backfire after some time, because of long sleep duration

**Modify cronjob**

If you are using plain cron (not systemd timer), you can actually create a custom entry inside of `/etc/cron.d/`, and then modify it from your own script

Let's say you'll create a file `/etc/cron.d/clicker` with the following content:

```
33 23 * * * /root/clicker.sh
```

You can store your command as CRON_COMMAND with

```
CRON_COMMAND="$(cut -d ' ' -f 6- /etc/cron.d/clicker)"
```

CRON_MINUTE with

```
CRON_MINUTE="$(cut -d ' ' -f 1 /etc/cron.d/clicker)"
```

CRON_HOUR with

```
CRON_HOUR="$(cut -d ' ' -f 2 /etc/cron.d/clicker)"
```

Then modify your expression to your liking, i.e. to append one more minute to CRON_MINUTE you can use

```
CRON_MINUTE="$(($CRON_MINUTE + 1 ))"
```

And then recreate this file with

```
echo "$CRON_MINUTE $CRON_HOUR * * * $CRON_COMMAND" > /etc/cron.d/clicker
```

You should implement your own logic to not overflow minutes/hours. One more caveat is that you have to be sure that your script won't modify cron entry before your new time, or it will run every minute and self increment each time.

Comment: thanks, I went with counter approach, works as expected